# How to expand a XIP file to an external drive when having low space on the drive where MacOS is installed?

Tags: macos, terminal, xcode, external-disk

I am running Xcode from an external drive because now the size ballooned to ~30GB and I don't have that much free space. I'm using 12.3 but as 12.4 got released I would like to upgrade.

I downloaded the Xcode_12.4.xip to the external drive, the problem is, how I am going to expand the Xcode_12.4.xip file? Clicking directly or using the xip -x command from the terminal first writes the output to my main drive, then transfers it to the external drive which means I need to have about 30GB on my main drive.

Is there a way to do the expanding directly on the external drive? I have enough space there.

Comment: Any solution @mrtksn

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution for me was to upgrade my SSD.

Comment: I have the external space as 1TB. If I try to expand the xip, it shows there is no enough space.

Comment: Yep, it first expands it on the primary drive and then will copy it to the external drive. I ended up upgrading my internal SSD and  later I got a new Macbook. Maybe it can be possible to modify an open source compression utility to use the external drive directly or maybe it could be possible to fake the temp directory(through a VM? through Symbolic link?) but I did not dive that deep into the issue as I was already considering an upgrade.

Comment: Without expanding using the primary drive, Is this possible?